# Python перестал корректно работать после попытки смены IP через Psiphon

Tags: python, bootstrap, ip, pip, idle

Много раз пробовал переустановить `python`, но так как я здесь это не помогло, так же и не помогла установка других версий `python'а`, в процессе установки она всегда останавливалась на моменте, когда устанавливается `Bootstrap`(я не знаю что это)).

Также после смены ай пи перестал работать IDLE и Unity. На счёт Unity я мало что знаю, но В IDLE ошибкой является `Port Binding Erro`r.
Вот полный текст ошибки:

```
IDLE can't bind to a TCP/IP port, which is necessary to communicate with its Python execution server. This might be because no networking is installed on this computer. Run IDLE with the -n command line switch to start without a subprocess and refer to Help/IDLE Help 'Running without a subprocess' for further details.
```

P.S. Я не думаю что это важно, но пока я работал с psiphon'ом avast заблокировал его.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего проверить работу Python при системном ip в настройках сети
При других условиях Python может не работать

Comment: я немножко не понимаю о чём ты, если ты об отключении psiphon'а то это уже давно за меня сделал антивирус